# terraform arm template deployment outputs not available on redeploy

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-resource-manager, terraform-provider-azure

I am trying to code my environment in terraform. In the environment, I use a SQL virtual machine ARM template since this is not yet available in terraform. I also want to backup this SQL VM in an RSV. For this, I would need the resource ID of the SQL VM. At the moment, I am using outputs in the ARM template like this:

```
"sql_vm_id": {
            "type": "string",
            "value": "[resourceId('Microsoft.SqlVirtualMachine/SqlVirtualMachines', parameters('virtualMachineName'))]"
        }
```

and I reference this output in my terraform code like this:

```
sourceResourceId = azurerm_template_deployment.sqlvm[count.index].outputs["sql_vm_id"]
```

and the deployment succeeds the first time. However, when I retry my deployment, I get the following error:

```
Error: Invalid index

  on modules\sqlVirtualMachine\sqlVirtualMachine.tf line 135, in resource "azurerm_template_deployment" "sqlvmbackup":
 135:     sourceResourceId = azurerm_template_deployment.sqlvm[count.index].outputs["sql_vm_id"]
    |----------------
    | azurerm_template_deployment.sqlvm is tuple with 1 element
    | count.index is 0

The given key does not identify an element in this collection value.
```

So it looks like the outputs of the ARM template are not retrieved the second time I try my deployment and hence it cannot find this output anymore. The deployment mode is incremental for the ARM template deployment in terraform. Putting it to complete will not help since I do not want to delete all other resources in my resource group.

The error says invalid index, so at first, I thought it was a problem with the index, however, when I change the `outputs["sql_vm_id"]` to `name`, the deployment plan is able to continue (it fails later on ofcourse because the name cannot be used as the ID). However, this shows that count.index is valid.

Is there an option to retrieve the outputs of the ARM template when redeploying the terraform code?

Comment: looks like a bug, tbh. Output would be there as long as the deployment is there

Comment: Can you share the terraform file?

Comment: Just add the Issue from the azurem provider issur here: https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-azurerm/pull/5263

Looks like it isn't far off being released if some PR comments can be resolved